# Pull GetOption() variable into jQuery dynamically created html

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, options

I have a page with the following markup in the site theme footer:

```
<div id="modalpopup"><div id="inside"></div></div>
```

I have a variable in the WP db I can retrieve via `GetOption()` which I would like to stuff into that `div#inside` on page load via jQuery.

When I've done AJAX before it's always been upon the user hitting a button to cause a POST, but this is a bit different so I'm kinda stuck.

I need to retrieve that variable from the db, send it to the jQuery function and then have the HTML generated rendered all -before- the page loads.

Ideas?

Comment: If you need this to load before the  page loads, why do you need to do this with jQuery? Why not do it with PHP?

Comment: Because the code I posted is built into the theme and is used all over the place for various popups. The idea is that 'modalpopup' is available for every page to use as a container for modal popup windows.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't run Javascript before the page loads. Javascript runs client-side, in the browser. The page has to load in order for that to happen. There is information missing from this question and it is beginning to look like a pure Javascript question which would be off-topic per the [faq]. Please try to clarify.

Comment: It's not a 'pure javascript question'. The page loads with the skeletion markup I indicated. And then -somehow- I want to dynamically grab a value from the WP theme option (which I assume is PHP) and -then- pass that string off to a jQuery function to stuff it into the #inside div. If there were a form and button involved I'd know what to do with AJAX. I want to know how to trigger that behaviour -without- a form... just on page load.

Comment: You still do it with AJAX, which you claim to know how to do, you just fire the function on [`jQuery(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) instead of on `submit` or on `click`...

Comment: Yes I do claim that. Thanks. I think I was stuck on the idea of 'forms' as that has been the only trigger I have used. Will give it a shot.

Comment: As s_ha_dum said, the technique is to simply call jQuery.ajax() from the ready event. The only thing I want to add is that, for my kind of application, it is important to put the work that needs to be done with the loaded data, into the success parameter function. (Since AJAX is -asynchronous-.) Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: @s_ha_dum if you want to add your comment as an 'Answer' I will mark it as my accepted answer as it's what I have ended up using. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would still do this with AJAX, except that instead of firing on some event like a 'click', or 'hover', or `submit`, you would fire the Javascript function on [`jQuery(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) instead. That will execute immediately on page load. It doesn't let you execute the code *before* the page loads as your question states but you can't run Javascript before the page loads. Javascript runs client-side, in the browser. The page has to load in order for that to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible solutions here-

**Solution one** is to not hardcode the modal markup into the template and instead use the [`wp_footer`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) action to insert it, along with your data:

```
function wpa_wp_footer(){
    $someval = 'foo'; // get_option results
    echo '<div id="modalpopup"><div id="inside">' . $someval . '</div></div>';
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpa_wp_footer' );
```

Personally, I would do it this way, as simple as it gets, keeps it theme-agnostic.

**Solution two** is more in line with your original idea, and gets the data to javascript so you can insert it yourself. But instead of making a separate request for the data via ajax, [localize the script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to have the data printed to the page when it's rendered.

Here's your standard [enqueue](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for adding javascript to a theme, along with the localize call to add extra data.

```
function wpa_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'wpa_script', // script handle
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js',
        array('jquery'),
        null,
        true
    );
    // do your get_option here to set whatever data you're passing
    $script_data = array(
        'some_var' => 'someval'
    );
    wp_localize_script(
        'wpa_script', // the script handle enqueued above
        'wpa_data',
        $script_data
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa_scripts' );
```

Then in your javascript, access the data like:

```
jQuery('#inside').html( wpa_data.some_var );
```

Comment: I have to do some investigating, but wp_localize_script looks -real- promising. Thanks for the example! I got my AJAX solution working in about 10 minutes, but this looks more intuitive. I can't use your 1st solution as there is too much 'stuff' that happens on virtually every page with js and those divs.